# Geo.Lua function GEOMETRYFILTER and Redis

Tags: redis, lua

I'm trying to figure out how to actually do a call to GEOMETRYFILTER function in geo.lua since documentation is not very clear to me:

https://github.com/RedisLabs/geo.lua#GEOMETRYFILTER

What exactly do these parameters means and how do I call this function from Redis-cli? I was not able to find any example on google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

geo.lua's author here - IIRC it involves first creating a polyhash to describe the filter and then providing it along with the geoset to the library. Performance is quite horrible as everything is done in Lua.

FYI - that library is no longer maintained.

Comment: Thank you kindly Sir :) this information is very helpful.